# Kotlin and AWS Lambda: How to implement secure authentication like OAUTH2

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda

This is a **question of architecture**. What I tried yet: *Research, research, research.*

I want to deploy various **microservices with AWS Lambda**. These should be accessible for authenticated users via Web and Android App.

**Question 1:** How to securely store AWS Gateway API keys (secrets) in an Android Kotlin / Webview app? Is Android Keystore the right (secure) answer?

**Question 2:** What's the best, secure way to make user login happen? Should the login be located at Lambda or inside the app? Again, how to securely store login data on Android? Could a cookie-based Web-Authentication be the answer (aka *"Keep me logged in"*)?

**The goal / my issue** is that I want the Android App user to enter his / her login data only once in the App and never be asked again for login at my Lambda Microservices. I'm aware that API Credentials and Login are two different problems here.

Example projects maybe?

This is not for critical data like banking, but still I want to follow best practices as much as I can in terms of sec.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you have researched on [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) or not but it can be used to provide authentication for both user interfaces and for APIs. It can easily be integrated with Lambda/API gateway.

> As an alternative to using IAM roles and policies or Lambda
>   authorizers (formerly known as custom authorizers), you can use an
>   Amazon Cognito user pool to control who can access your API in Amazon
>   API Gateway.

Further reading : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll research into that and then maybe update my question - or give  you the price. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps I have some cloud demo sample UIs that connect to lambdas and use Cognito. You can run them starting here: https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/

The blog has some write ups on how it all fits together - see the index page for further details - there is a post on UI token storage for example.

Long lasting sessions can be managed via refresh tokens - but your apps should still deal with token and session expiry - and scenarios such as logging on as a different user for testing.